# Print the value of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

In Javascript code, how do you access a value in an object?

Here is an example

```js
var a = [{
  "temp": true
}];
console.log(a['temp']);
```

My expected output is `true`, however, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: `a` isn't an object, it's an array *that contains an object*. Please read up on basic JS syntax.

Comment: The expected value is `undefined`, where have you defined `a.temp`?

Comment: You should use `console.log(a[0]['temp']);`

Comment: Use `a[0].temp` or `a[0]['temp']`.

Comment: a[0].temp or a[0]['temp'] is giving undefined

Comment: @DineshAhuja [Did you even try](https://jsfiddle.net/t9m7ajL5/)?

Answer (score 0):

As `a` is assigned value which is an array. And it contains only value which is object. So for getting value of `temp` you need to get object which is at 0 index of `a`. Then you can go for it's property.

```js
var a = [{"temp": true}];
alert(a[0]['temp']);
console.log(a[0]['temp']);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @AndrewBone I will consider your suggestion and keep that in mind. Thanks.